# Weightpaint can't suptract or change weight of brush

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode, brushes

I downloaded a rig from a youtuber that is meant for easy animation/Mocap Clean Up.
I assigned the Armature to the new Model and then started weightpainting.
Issue:
When i select **subtract** the brush **adds weight** to the model + i can't change the fall off or the weight that is getting applyed to the Model (even on other brushes like Add or Mix).

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello maybe share your file or at least a part?

Comment: you can use https://blend-exchange.com/  read the instructions

Comment: Yes didn't thought of it, but now i updated the post with the Blender file.

Comment: You need to disable the Auto-Normalize option but I'm trying to understand the reason why...

Comment: Thank you so much :) it works now

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the *Auto-Normalize* option but maybe someone will explain why it paints vertices that are not part of any vertex group even though you are in *Subtract* mode:

[image]